# Vue2.0 How to remove space in array value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How could i remove the space in array value and retrieve the value by [0],[1] etc

on data side there is nums:"9 2 3 0 0" , i wish to remove the space between the number and retrieve starting from 【0】【1】 move in the the li on item.nums. Kindly advise

HTML:

```
<section class="flex-box betting-main">
      <div class="display-flex lottery-info" v-for="item in resultRecord.history">
        <div class="fl">
          <span>第{{item.issueno}}期</span>
          <!--<p style="margin-left: 4rem;">29期</p>-->
        </div>
        <div class="fr">
          <div class="display-flex">
            <ul class="flex-box lottery-num">
              <li>{{item.nums }}</li>
              <li>{{item.nums}}</li>
              <li>{{item.nums}}</li>
              <li>{{item.nums}}</li>
              <li>{{item.nums}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

SCRIPT :

```
export default {
    data () {
      return {
        resultRecord: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      goback: function(){
        this.$router.go(-1);

      }

    },
    created() {
      var params = {
        gameID: 10
      }
      var _this = this
      RecordList.LoadRecordList(params,function(res){

        _this.resultRecord = res.data


      });
    },

  }
```

Comment: Can you post what the array looks like?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal its was a String where containt nums:"9 3 0 2 0"

Comment: So, something like `["9 3 0 2 0"]` ?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Yup , correct . Kindly advise i have no clue how to solve this

Comment: Sorry for asking this but just to be sure, you want `["9 3 0 2 0"]` to `[9, 3, 2, 0]` ?

Comment: If it's an array with 1 string of number separated by spaces, array[0].split(" ") will give you an array of string, being each string a number.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal I found an solution by using filter and item.nums | at(0)

Comment: If it works well, cheers but I feel @Potray had a simpler way of doing it, didn't that work out?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal potray method not longer available for vue2.0

Comment: @MorganNg why would String.prototype.split should have any relation with version of VueJS ? It's native JS method placed on String prototype...